# Disappearing level curves on ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, mesh

The mesh of level curves on `ParametricPlot3D[]` does not work for some functions.
For many functions it works normally, e.g.:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[p],r*Sin[p],r},{r,0,2},{p,0,2Pi},MeshFunctions->{(#3&)}]
```

[image]

But whenever the inverse occurs, the mesh disappears

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[p],r*Sin[p],1/r},{r,0,2},{p,0,2 Pi},MeshFunctions->{(#3&)}]
```

[image]

It seems that this issue is due to a bug (version 13.0). Do you have any idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the levels using the option `Mesh`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[p], r*Sin[p], 1/r}, {r, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 15, 50]}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working as needed. Apparently, we had to "force" the drawing of these lines because the automaton failed.